# NetBeans locks on startup on Ubuntu 64

Tags: java, netbeans, installation

I made the mistake of installing NetBeans as root:

```
sudo sh /opt/myDirectory/netbeansInstaller.sh
```

I installed it, launched it, and created a dummy project just to get familiar with it. Then I closed NetBeans and came back to it later on in the day. When I try to open/run NetBeans as my normal user, it launches with all sorts of error messages complaining about **denied permissions**.

So I uninstalled NetBeans completely using the uninstaller, and even deleted the project I created with it.  I even deleted the installer itself out of my Downloads folder.

I re-installed NetBeans as normal user, and am still getting permissions errors. Now what happens is it launches, generates some error popups, and then freezes completely. **I notice that it is still attempting to launch my deleted project by default**!

Here is what I think is happening:

1. I run NetBeans as normal user
2. NetBeans has cached, somewhere, that my old project (which was created when I was using the old NB install as root) is the project to load at startup
3. It automatically complains that it can't load the project properly because I'm not root
4. It can't find my old project (because its deleted) and so it freezes in this "wait state"

Has anybody else ever had this problem? Any way to force NetBeans (perhaps from the terminal) to do a "clean load" where it won't attempt to load any projects? ANy other obvious solutions?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this also happen when you launch netbeans as another, freshly created, user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try deleting the `.netbeans` folders in the `/root` and in your home directory respectively. Netbeans maybe wants to read the `/root/.netbeans` folder for which it has no permission.